# How to show products in Woocommerce Product Vendor plugin vendor page if group product is showed in shop page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements

i’ve added the following code in functions.php as I want to show only group product into the woocommerce shop page. The code works. The issue is that single products are not then showed up under each vendor page of Product Vendor plugin.

Plugin support told me that to solve this my code below needs a condition added, so that it runs only on certain pages - otherwise it is going to affect the entire site.....

Unfortunately i do not know how to do that.

YOUR support will be most welcome!

```
'''/**
* Show Only Grouped Products in Woocommerce
*/

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'only_grouped_products', 20, 1 );
function only_grouped_products( $tax_query ){
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'product_type',
        'field'     => 'name',
        'terms'     => array('grouped'),
    );
    return $tax_query;
}'''
```

Comment: use conditions such as is_page(), is_page_template(), is_category(), is_tax(),is_category() . You can google each one of them and read about them in wordpress docs. I am not sure which plugin you are using but most have own conditions too. Woocommerce have own conditions too - https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/. Example run only if we are on page with id 7 if(is_page('7')) {$tax_query[] = array(...) } return $tax_query;

Comment: Also woocommerce_product_query will affect shop only - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/278390/how-to-exclude-products-by-tag-from-woocommerce-shop-page

Comment: the problem is that the vendor page is also a shop page...the plugin is Product Vendor and in fact is an extension of Woocommerce

Comment: Maybe this will help ? https://gist.github.com/bentasm1/56a56f8996b289c076f8 . Add line 13,14,15 where if ( $vendor_id ) should be if ( !$vendor_id ) { your tax_query} . I dont have this plugin to test

Comment: ... the only thing i know is that: Overwriting the template file will not work well any longer.

The output now uses hooks via the function: `display_vendor_logo_profile()` located in `/includes/class-wc-product-vendors-vendor-frontend.php`....

Answer (score 0):

I've find the solution:

```
/**
* Show Only Grouped Products in Woocommerce
*/

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 
'prefix_custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

function prefix_custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

if( is_shop() || is_page('products-portfolio') ) {

    $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );

    $tax_query[] = array(
           'taxonomy' => 'product_type',
           'field'    => 'name',
           'terms'    => array( 'grouped'), // set product categories here
    );
    $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
}
elseif( is_product_category() ) {

    $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );

    $tax_query[] = array(
           'taxonomy' => 'product_type',
           'field'    => 'name',
           'terms'    => array( 'grouped'), // set product categories here
    );
    $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
}
elseif( is_product_tag() ) {

    $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );

    $tax_query[] = array(
           'taxonomy' => 'product_type',
           'field'    => 'name',
           'terms'    => array( 'grouped'), // set product categories here
    );
    $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
}
else {
}
```

}